# css image placement

Tags: css, image, containers

I have a full width container (100%) and i like to have a image inside  NOT A BACKGROUND for clicking purpose...

How can i center the image into the container horizontally ?

here is a sample : http://notrepanorama.com/test/

---

Solution  :

```
.centerimage {
    margin-left: -960px;
    width: 1920px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

Since i have found the solution to my problem, i will give the checked (√) to the one the will tell me why the spacing before the blue box, it's should be adjacent to the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.container img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="image.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
text-align: center;
}
```